# DB2 variable with timestamp

Tags: sql, db2

I am not well versed with DB2 syntax at all, so need some guidance, following is ms sql code that I am trying to convert in DB2(version 8.2.4) code

```
declare @d datetime, @mydate varchar(16)
set @d = GETDATE()
--create formatted datetime[yyyyMMdd-hhmmss]
set @mydate = convert(varchar,@d,112)+'-  '+convert(varchar,datepart(hh,@d))+convert(varchar,datepart(mi,@d))+convert(varchar,datepart(ss,@d))
select @mydate as MyDate
```

However I am having absolutely no luck, I have tried to assign variable using following syntax

```
DECLARE c_date Date;
SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP INTO c_date FROM SYSIBM.SYSDUMMY1
```

with no luck..I used another format to create variable as well(CREATE VARIABLE), I googled and found few resources but for some reasons, in my case I was not able to do what I am trying to do..hope some one can shed some light..
Thanks

Comment: Define "no luck". `DATE` and `TIMESTAMP` are different data types, so you cannot assign a timestamp value to a date variable. Firstly you need to declare `c_date` as `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: I attempted many things to assign a value to a variable but was unsuccessful..I don't have my test pc on hand, but if you look at my MS SQL code can you guide how I can achieve that?

Comment: If you explain what is it that you're trying to achieve, I might be able to suggest something. As it is now, your code doesn't make much sense as it only displays a timestamp. I doubt this is what you're after.

Comment: I think what I am after is somehow get exactly duplicate the MS SQL code that I have posted above, and I am not able to do this in DB2..THere is another functionality which comes once I have the correct date values in the variable. Pls take a look at SQL code and help me duplicate that code using DB2 Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that DB2 tiemstamps are very different from MySql or Oracle timestamps

You can use the following systax to assign timestamps

```
TSCOL = '2014-12-31-23:59:59.123456'  -- notice microseconds are required !!
TSCOL = '2014-12-31 23:59:59.123456'  -- for newer versions of DB2 with ISO dateformat set!!
```

or

```
TSCOL = TIMESTAMP(DATECOL,TIMECOL)
```

Comment: Microseconds are not required, actually, especially this being DB2 8.2

Comment: Hi James, I think for some reasons my question is not clear, What I want is to assign a variable a date for example say I want following variable
DECLARE VARIABLE myDate varchar(50)
Then I want to assign some value to it which is returned from a query, such as
set myDate = Select xyz from tableAbc
I have tried following syntax as well
select xyz into myDate from tableAbc

This is what I am struggling with, can you help  me understand why whatever I try I can not seem to assign value to a variable?

Answer (score 0):

It appears that you're trying to get the current timestamp, but formatted in a certain way.  Since DB2 8.2 doesn't have a useful `TIMESTAMP_FORMAT` function, you can use the following:

```
select 
    cast(int(current date) as char(8)) || '-' || cast(int(current time) as char(6)) as mydate 
from 
    sysibm.sysdummy1
```

This returns:

```
MYDATE              
---------------
20131203-234912
```

Comment: For more information about that old and deprecated DB2 version, please check this InfoCenter: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v8/index.jsp Current DB2 version is 10.5

Comment: can you put the out put of your query in a variable? Thats where I am stuck.....thanks ur qeury brings me closer

Comment: If you are writing a stored procedure, then sure, you can assign it to a variable.  (`set myvar = cast...`).  But outside of a stored proc you can't, because DB2 8.2 doesn't allow compound SQL.